# Numpy Array with different types of features for sci-kitLearn dataset API in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataset, scikit-learn

I am trying to perform machine learning using sci-kitLearn on a dataset parsed from a json file. To use the dataset API in sci-kitLearn I need a Numpy array of shape (n_samples * n_features).

I have this data encoded as a nested Python list where the list is size 'X' (some large amount of samples) and each element is of type [int, float, int] (3 features).

Ex:  [ [int, float, int] , [int, float, int] , ... ]

I need to convert this into a numpy array that will will function properly with the sci-kitLearn dataset but I cannot seem to create a numpy array that supports different types for each column.

Numpy arrays are genearally homogenous but I find it hard to believe that different types of features/columns in a dataset remains a flaw in using this API and I have seen examples where different types of features are used.

The documentation on loading your own dataset is poor : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html. Any help created the numpy array and/or using the dataset API would be greatly appreciated.

My code is posted below (although the problem is what to do next) :

```
with open('bc_mp_at_blockchain.json') as data_:
mp_json = json.load(data_)

with open('bc_tv_at_blockchain.json') as data:
    tv_json = json.load(data)

# access dictionary of length 1 that list of values
list_of_mpdata = mp_json['values']
list_of_tvdata = tv_json['values']

# ensure both sets of data start on the same day
assert ( list_of_mpdata[0]['x'] == list_of_tvdata[0]['x'] )

#concatenate lists as necessary
combined_list = []
for mp_dict, tv_dict in zip(list_of_mpdata, list_of_tvdata) :
    combined_list.append([ mp_dict['x'], mp_dict['y'], tv_dict['y'] ])

# combined_list is now a list of [int,float,int] lists
```

Comment: To answer your question about features, I don't imagine it matters — all the values can probably be represented by floats. Can you provide a link to the scikit-learn method you're trying to use?

Comment: for example : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA

Comment: That function accepts the `n_samples * n_features` array as floats (I use this daily).

Comment: its all working now. complete user error. my fault : |

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of lists you can convert this to a `numpy` array with `np.array(combined_list)`. This will be in the shape where the length of the outer list is in the first dimension (down), e.g.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)
```

If I understand correctly that should be the correct n_samples*n_features order for scikit, but if not you can transpose the array using:

```
>>> a = a.T
>>> a.shape
(3, 2)
```

Comment: This does not work. The values in my list become messed up. Example : [[  1.23100650e+09   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]. The conversion is not happening correctly, however I have ensured the type of element is [int, float, int]

Comment: In what way is the conversion not happening correctly? Can you provide an example of your input data (e.g. what are the values of `mp_dict['x'], mp_dict['y'], tv_dict['y']`)

Comment: example input data element : [1410718505, 475.49, 33003201] & an example output data element : [ 1.23100650e+09   0.00000000e+00    0.00000000e+00]

Comment: Using `np.array([1410718505, 475.49, 33003201])` gives `array([  1.41071850e+09,   4.75490000e+02,   3.30032010e+07])` so I suspect the error is elsewhere?

Comment: Wow, it was completely my mistake. Assumed incorrect ordering of the actual file I was reading. The values are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a numpy array with `numpy.array(combined_list)`and all the values will be converted to `float`.
`Int` to `float` conversion does not usually affect any machine learning analysis.

Comment: This does not work. The values in my list become messed up. Example : [[ 1.23100650e+09 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]. The conversion is not happening correctly, however I have ensured the type of element is [int, float, int]. I have also tried using the dtype parameter with no success. Suggestions on that may be helpful.

Comment: numpy.array([[[1410718505, 475.49, 33003201]]]) creates a numpy float array of shape (1,3) with values [[1.41071850e+09,   4.75490000e+02,   3.30032010e+07]]

Could you give an example which does not work as expected?